# LNK2019 símbolo externo public: bool __thiscall .... sin resolver

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Estoy tratando de compilar una herramienta para mi proyecto. He resuelto todos los problemas hasta ahora, pero no logro encontrar la solución para el problema actual.

Si alguno me podría dar una mano lo agradecería, Gracias.

NtlScriptEncrypter.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "NtlScriptEncrypter.h"
#include "NtlXMLDoc.h"
#include "NtlFileSerializer.h"

#define CRYPT_PASSWORD "!@*&(agebreak"

CNtlScriptEncrypter::CNtlScriptEncrypter(void)
{
}

CNtlScriptEncrypter::~CNtlScriptEncrypter(void)
{
}

/**
 * ÄÁÇÇ±× ¼³Á¤ ÆÄÀÏÀ» ·ÎµåÇÑ´Ù. È®ÀåÀÚ·Î XML,EDF¸¦ ±¸º°ÇÑ´Ù.
 * \param pConfigData ·ÎµåÇÑ µ¥ÀÌÅÍ¸¦ ÀúÀåÇÒ Æ÷ÀÎÅÍ
 * \param szFileName ·ÎµåÇÒ ÆÄÀÏ ÀÌ¸§
 * \return 
 */
BOOL CNtlScriptEncrypter::LoadConfigOption( OUT SConfigData* pConfigData, char* szFileName ) 
{
    if(!pConfigData || !szFileName)
        return FALSE;

    char szDrive[128]   = {0,};
    char szdir[128]     = {0,};
    char szfName[128]   = {0,};
    char szExt[128]     = {0,};
    _splitpath_s(szFileName, szDrive, szdir, szfName, szExt);    
    _strlwr_s(szExt);
    
    if(strcmp(szExt, ".xml") == 0)
    {
        return LoadConfigOptionXML(pConfigData, szFileName);
    }
    else if(strcmp(szExt, ".edf") == 0)
    {
        return LoadConfigOptionENC(pConfigData, szFileName);
    }

    return FALSE;
}

BOOL CNtlScriptEncrypter::LoadConfigOptionXML( OUT SConfigData* pConfigData, char* szFileName ) 
{
    CNtlXMLDoc doc;
    doc.Create();

    // xml doc load
    if(doc.Load( (char*)szFileName ) == false)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    char chBuffer[1024];

    // config operationÀ» ¾ò¾î¿Â´Ù.
    IXMLDOMNode* pNode = doc.SelectSingleNode((char*)"/config_options/op");

    if(!doc.GetTextWithAttributeName(pNode, "ver", chBuffer, 1024))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if(!doc.GetTextWithAttributeName(pNode, "ip", chBuffer, 1024))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    pConfigData->strAddr = chBuffer;

    if(!doc.GetTextWithAttributeName(pNode, "port", chBuffer, 1024))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    pConfigData->dwPort = (DWORD)atoi(chBuffer);

    pNode->Release(); 

    // config localÀ» ¾ò¾î¿Â´Ù.

    pNode = doc.SelectSingleNode((char*)"/config_options/local");

    if(!doc.GetTextWithAttributeName(pNode, "ver", chBuffer, 1024))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if(!doc.GetTextWithAttributeName(pNode, "local_dsp", chBuffer, 1024))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    pConfigData->strLocalDsp = chBuffer;

    if(!doc.GetTextWithAttributeName(pNode, "local_sync_dsp", chBuffer, 1024))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    pConfigData->strLocalSyncDsp = chBuffer;

    // Bug Trap
    pNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/config_options/BUGTRAP");
    if(doc.GetTextWithAttributeName(pNode, "ip", chBuffer, 1024))
    {
        pConfigData->strBugTrapServerIP = chBuffer;
    }

    if(doc.GetTextWithAttributeName(pNode, "port", chBuffer, 1024))
    {
        pConfigData->dwBugTrapServerPort = atoi(chBuffer);        
    }

    pNode->Release(); 

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CNtlScriptEncrypter::LoadConfigOptionENC( OUT SConfigData* pConfigData, char* szFileName ) 
{
    USES_CONVERSION;

    CNtlFileSerializer nsl(1024 * 1024, 1024 * 1024);

    WCHAR* wszFileName;
    WCHAR* wszCryptPassword;

    mbstowcs(wszFileName, szFileName, sizeof(szFileName));
    mbstowcs(wszCryptPassword, CRYPT_PASSWORD, sizeof(CRYPT_PASSWORD));

    if (!nsl.LoadFile(wszFileName, TRUE, wszCryptPassword))
        return FALSE;

    std::string strAddr = "";
    std::string strLocalDsp = "";
    std::string strLocalSyncDsp = "";
    std::string strBugTrapServerIP ="";

    nsl>>strAddr;
    nsl>>pConfigData->dwPort;
    nsl>>strLocalDsp;
    nsl>>strLocalSyncDsp;
    nsl>>strBugTrapServerIP;
    nsl>>pConfigData->dwBugTrapServerPort;

    pConfigData->strAddr = A2W(strAddr.c_str());
    pConfigData->strLocalDsp = A2W(strLocalDsp.c_str());
    pConfigData->strLocalSyncDsp = A2W(strLocalSyncDsp.c_str());
    pConfigData->strBugTrapServerIP = A2W(strBugTrapServerIP.c_str());

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CNtlScriptEncrypter::SaveConfigOption(SConfigData* pConfigData, char* szFileName, BOOL bEncrypt /* = FALSE */)
{
    if(!pConfigData || !szFileName)
        return FALSE;

    if(bEncrypt)
    {
        return SaveConfigOptionENC(pConfigData, szFileName, CRYPT_PASSWORD);
    }
    else
    {
        return SaveConfigOptionXML(pConfigData, szFileName);
    }    
}

BOOL CNtlScriptEncrypter::SaveConfigOptionXML( SConfigData* pConfigData, char* szFileName ) 
{
    USES_CONVERSION;

    CNtlXMLDoc doc;
    doc.Create();

    IXMLDOMProcessingInstruction* pPI    = NULL;        

    doc.GetDocument()->createProcessingInstruction(L"xml", L"version=\"1.0\" encoding = \"UTF-8\"", &pPI);
    if(!pPI)
        return FALSE;
    doc.GetDocument()->appendChild(pPI, NULL);

    IXMLDOMElement*     pElemRoot = NULL;                ///< Root Element
    IXMLDOMElement*     pElemOp = NULL;
    IXMLDOMElement*     pElemLocal = NULL;
    IXMLDOMElement*     pElemBUGTrap = NULL;

    doc.GetDocument()->createElement(L"config_options", &pElemRoot);
    doc.GetDocument()->appendChild(pElemRoot, NULL);

    WCHAR wbuf[1204] = {0,};

    doc.GetDocument()->createElement(L"op", &pElemOp);
    pElemOp->setAttribute(L"ver", (_variant_t)L"0.1");
    pElemOp->setAttribute(L"ip", (_variant_t)pConfigData->strAddr);
    swprintf_s(wbuf, L"%d", pConfigData->dwPort);
    pElemOp->setAttribute(L"port", (_variant_t)wbuf);    

    doc.GetDocument()->createElement(L"local", &pElemLocal);
    pElemLocal->setAttribute(L"ver", (_variant_t)L"0.1");
    pElemLocal->setAttribute(L"local_dsp", (_variant_t)pConfigData->strLocalDsp);
    pElemLocal->setAttribute(L"local_sync_dsp", (_variant_t)pConfigData->strLocalSyncDsp);    

    doc.GetDocument()->createElement(L"BUGTRAP", &pElemBUGTrap);
    pElemBUGTrap->setAttribute(L"ip", (_variant_t)pConfigData->strBugTrapServerIP);
    swprintf_s(wbuf, L"%d", pConfigData->dwBugTrapServerPort);
    pElemBUGTrap->setAttribute(L"port", (_variant_t)wbuf);

    pElemRoot->appendChild(pElemOp, NULL);
    pElemRoot->appendChild(pElemLocal, NULL);
    pElemRoot->appendChild(pElemBUGTrap, NULL);

    doc.SetIndent(L"indent.xsl");
    HRESULT hr = doc.GetDocument()->save((_variant_t)szFileName);
    if(hr != S_OK)
        return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CNtlScriptEncrypter::SaveConfigOptionENC( SConfigData* pConfigData, char* szFileName, char* szCryptPassword ) 
{
    USES_CONVERSION;

    CNtlFileSerializer nsl(1024 * 1024, 1024 * 1024);

    std::string strAddr = W2A(pConfigData->strAddr);
    std::string strLocalDsp = W2A(pConfigData->strLocalDsp);
    std::string strLocalSyncDsp = W2A(pConfigData->strLocalSyncDsp);
    std::string strBugTrapServerIP = W2A(pConfigData->strBugTrapServerIP);

    nsl<<strAddr;
    nsl<<pConfigData->dwPort;
    nsl<<strLocalDsp;
    nsl<<strLocalSyncDsp;
    nsl<<strBugTrapServerIP;
    nsl<<pConfigData->dwBugTrapServerPort;

    return nsl.SaveFile(szFileName, TRUE, szCryptPassword);

    return TRUE;
}
```

NtlScriptEncrypter.h

```
class CNtlScriptEncrypter
{
public:
    CNtlScriptEncrypter(void);
    ~CNtlScriptEncrypter(void);

    static BOOL LoadConfigOption(OUT SConfigData* pConfigData, char* szFileName);             
    static BOOL SaveConfigOption(SConfigData* pConfigData, char* szFileName, BOOL bEncrypt = FALSE); 

protected:
    static BOOL LoadConfigOptionXML(OUT SConfigData* pConfigData, char* szFileName);
    static BOOL LoadConfigOptionENC(OUT SConfigData* pConfigData, char* szFileName);
    static BOOL SaveConfigOptionXML(SConfigData* pConfigData, char* szFileName);
    static BOOL SaveConfigOptionENC(SConfigData* pConfigData, char* szFileName, char* szCryptPassword);
};
```

NtlXMLDoc.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <comdef.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include "NtlXMLDoc.h"
//#include "NtlAssert.h"


class CCoInit
{
public:
    CCoInit( void )
    {
        ::CoInitialize( NULL );
    }

    ~CCoInit( void )
    {
        ::CoUninitialize();
    }
};

CCoInit g_CoInit;

CNtlXMLDoc::CNtlXMLDoc(void)
{
    Init();
}

CNtlXMLDoc::~CNtlXMLDoc(void)
{
    Destroy();
}

bool CNtlXMLDoc::Create()
{
    if (NULL != m_pXMLDocument)
        return false;

    HRESULT hResult;

    hResult = ::CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DOMDocument30), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IXMLDOMDocument), (void**)&m_pXMLDocument);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        ::CoInitialize( NULL );
        hResult = ::CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DOMDocument30), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IXMLDOMDocument), (void**)&m_pXMLDocument);
        if (FAILED(hResult))
        {
            Destroy();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (NULL == m_pXMLDocument)
    {
        Destroy();
        return false;
    }

    hResult = m_pXMLDocument->put_async(VARIANT_FALSE);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        Destroy();
        return false;
    }

    hResult = m_pXMLDocument->put_validateOnParse(VARIANT_FALSE);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        Destroy();
        return false;
    }

    hResult = m_pXMLDocument->put_resolveExternals(VARIANT_FALSE);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        Destroy();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool CNtlXMLDoc::Destroy()
{
    if (NULL != m_pXMLDocument)
    {
        m_pXMLDocument->Release();
        m_pXMLDocument = NULL;
    }

    m_bIsFileLoaded = false;

    return true;
}

void CNtlXMLDoc::Init()
{
    m_pXMLDocument = NULL;
    m_bIsFileLoaded = false;
}
bool CNtlXMLDoc::Load(WCHAR* pwszFileName, LONG* lLineNumber, BSTR* bstrErrorReasonString )
{
    if (false != m_bIsFileLoaded)
        return false;

    VARIANT_BOOL status = VARIANT_FALSE;
    HRESULT hResult = m_pXMLDocument->load((_variant_t)pwszFileName, &status);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (VARIANT_FALSE == status)
    {
        IXMLDOMParseError* pXMLError = NULL;
        m_pXMLDocument->get_parseError(&pXMLError);

        //BSTR bstrErrorReasonString;
        //LONG lLineNumber = 0;
        BSTR bstrSrcText;
        LONG lLinePosition = 0;

        pXMLError->get_srcText(&bstrSrcText);
        pXMLError->get_reason(bstrErrorReasonString);
        pXMLError->get_line(lLineNumber);
        pXMLError->get_linepos(&lLinePosition);

        //::SysFreeString(*bstrErrorReasonString);

        pXMLError->Release();

        return false;
    }

    m_bIsFileLoaded = true;

    return true;
}

bool CNtlXMLDoc::Load(WCHAR* pwszFileName )
{
    if (false != m_bIsFileLoaded)
        return false;

    VARIANT_BOOL status = VARIANT_FALSE;
    HRESULT hResult = m_pXMLDocument->load((_variant_t)pwszFileName, &status);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (VARIANT_FALSE == status)
    {
        IXMLDOMParseError* pXMLError = NULL;
        m_pXMLDocument->get_parseError(&pXMLError);

        BSTR bstrErrorReasonString;
        LONG lLineNumber = 0;
        BSTR bstrSrcText;
        LONG lLinePosition = 0;

        pXMLError->get_srcText(&bstrSrcText);
        pXMLError->get_reason(&bstrErrorReasonString);
        pXMLError->get_line(&lLineNumber);
        pXMLError->get_linepos(&lLinePosition);

        ::SysFreeString(bstrErrorReasonString);

        pXMLError->Release();

        return false;
    }

    m_bIsFileLoaded = true;

    return true;
}

bool CNtlXMLDoc::Load(char* pszFileName)
{
    if (false != m_bIsFileLoaded)
        return false;

    WCHAR wszUnicodeFileName[MAX_UNICODE_FILE_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    ZeroMemory(wszUnicodeFileName, sizeof(WCHAR) * (MAX_UNICODE_FILE_NAME_LENGTH + 1));

    int iWrittenChars = ::MultiByteToWideChar(GetACP(), 0, pszFileName, -1, wszUnicodeFileName, MAX_UNICODE_FILE_NAME_LENGTH);
    wszUnicodeFileName[MAX_UNICODE_FILE_NAME_LENGTH] = L'\0';

    if (0 == iWrittenChars)
        return false;

    return Load(wszUnicodeFileName);
}

bool CNtlXMLDoc::LoadXML( char* szXMLBuffer ) 
{
    USES_CONVERSION;

    if(false != m_bIsFileLoaded)
        return false;

    return LoadXML(A2W(szXMLBuffer));
}

bool CNtlXMLDoc::LoadXML( WCHAR* wszXMLBuffer ) 
{
    if (false != m_bIsFileLoaded)
        return false;

    VARIANT_BOOL status;    
    HRESULT hResult = m_pXMLDocument->loadXML(wszXMLBuffer, &status);

    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (VARIANT_FALSE == status)
    {
        IXMLDOMParseError* pXMLError = NULL;
        m_pXMLDocument->get_parseError(&pXMLError);

        BSTR bstrErrorReasonString;
        pXMLError->get_reason(&bstrErrorReasonString);
        ::SysFreeString(bstrErrorReasonString);

        pXMLError->Release();

        return false;
    }

    m_bIsFileLoaded = true;

    return true;
}


IXMLDOMNode* CNtlXMLDoc::SelectSingleNode(WCHAR* pwszXPath)
{
    if (false == m_bIsFileLoaded)
        return NULL;
    if (NULL == pwszXPath)
        return NULL;

    IXMLDOMNode* pXMLNode = NULL;

    BSTR bstrXPath = ::SysAllocString(pwszXPath);
    HRESULT hResult = m_pXMLDocument->selectSingleNode(bstrXPath, &pXMLNode);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        ::SysFreeString(bstrXPath);
        return NULL;
    }

    ::SysFreeString(bstrXPath);
    return pXMLNode;
}

IXMLDOMNode* CNtlXMLDoc::SelectSingleNode(char* pszXPath)
{
    if (false == m_bIsFileLoaded)
        return NULL;

    WCHAR wszUnicodeXPath[MAX_UNICODE_XPATH_LENGTH + 1];
    ZeroMemory(wszUnicodeXPath, sizeof(WCHAR) * (MAX_UNICODE_XPATH_LENGTH + 1));

    int iWrittenChars = ::MultiByteToWideChar(GetACP(), 0, pszXPath, -1, wszUnicodeXPath, MAX_UNICODE_XPATH_LENGTH);
    wszUnicodeXPath[MAX_UNICODE_XPATH_LENGTH] = L'\0';

    if (0 == iWrittenChars)
        return NULL;

    return SelectSingleNode(wszUnicodeXPath);
}

IXMLDOMNodeList* CNtlXMLDoc::SelectNodeList(WCHAR* pwszXPath)
{
    if (false == m_bIsFileLoaded)
        return NULL;
    if (NULL == pwszXPath)
        return NULL;

    IXMLDOMNodeList* pXMLNodeList = NULL;

    BSTR bstrXPath = ::SysAllocString(pwszXPath);
    HRESULT hResult = m_pXMLDocument->selectNodes(bstrXPath, &pXMLNodeList);
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        ::SysFreeString(bstrXPath);
        return NULL;
    }

    ::SysFreeString(bstrXPath);
    return pXMLNodeList;
}

IXMLDOMNodeList* CNtlXMLDoc::SelectNodeList(char* pszXPath)
{
    if (false == m_bIsFileLoaded)
        return NULL;

    WCHAR wszUnicodeXPath[MAX_UNICODE_XPATH_LENGTH + 1];
    ZeroMemory(wszUnicodeXPath, sizeof(WCHAR) * (MAX_UNICODE_XPATH_LENGTH + 1));

    int iWrittenChars = ::MultiByteToWideChar(GetACP(), 0, pszXPath, -1, wszUnicodeXPath, MAX_UNICODE_XPATH_LENGTH);
    wszUnicodeXPath[MAX_UNICODE_XPATH_LENGTH] = L'\0';

    if (0 == iWrittenChars)
        return NULL;

    return SelectNodeList(wszUnicodeXPath);
}

bool CNtlXMLDoc::GetTextWithAttributeName(IXMLDOMNode* pNode, WCHAR* pwszAttributeName, WCHAR* pwszResultText, int nBufferSizeInWChars)
{
    if (NULL == pNode || NULL == pwszAttributeName || NULL == pwszResultText)
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("NULL == pNode || NULL == pwszAttributeName || NULL == pwszResultText");
        return false;
    }
    if (0 >= nBufferSizeInWChars)
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("0 >= nBufferSizeInWChars");
        return false;
    }

    IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap* pMap = NULL;
    pNode->get_attributes(&pMap);
    if (NULL == pMap)
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("Couldn't get the attribute list from the given IXMLDOMNode.");
        return false;
    }

    IXMLDOMNode* pVirtualNode = NULL;
    pMap->getNamedItem(pwszAttributeName, &pVirtualNode);
    if (NULL == pVirtualNode)
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("Couldn't find the given attribute name.");
        return false;
    }

    VARIANT var;
    VariantInit(&var);
    pVirtualNode->get_nodeValue(&var);

    if (wcslen(V_BSTR(&var)) >= (size_t)nBufferSizeInWChars)
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("The buffer size is not enough to take the whole attribute value.");
        return false;
    }

    wcscpy_s(pwszResultText, nBufferSizeInWChars, V_BSTR(&var));

    return true;
}

bool CNtlXMLDoc::GetTextWithAttributeName(IXMLDOMNode* pNode, char* pszAttributeName, char* pszResultText, int nBufferSizeInBytes)
{
    if (NULL == pNode || NULL == pszAttributeName || NULL == pszResultText)
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("NULL == pNode || NULL == pszAttributeName || NULL == pszResultText");
        return false;
    }
    if (0 >= nBufferSizeInBytes)
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("0 >= nBufferSizeInBytes");
        return false;
    }

    int nRequiredBytes = 0;
    nRequiredBytes = MultiByteToWideChar(GetACP(), 0, pszAttributeName, -1, NULL, 0);
    if (0 == nRequiredBytes)
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("The given attribute name can't be converted into WCHAR type for some reason.");
        return false;
    }
    if (nRequiredBytes > (CNtlXMLDoc::MAX_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IN_WCHAR + 1))
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("The given attribute name is too long.");
        return false;
    }

    WCHAR pwszAttributeNameInWChar[CNtlXMLDoc::MAX_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IN_WCHAR + 1];

    int nUsedBufferSize = MultiByteToWideChar(GetACP(), 0, pszAttributeName, -1, pwszAttributeNameInWChar, (CNtlXMLDoc::MAX_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IN_WCHAR + 1));
    if (0 == nUsedBufferSize)
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("The given attribute name couldn't be converted into WCHAR type for some reason.");
        return false;
    }

    IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap* pMap = NULL;
    pNode->get_attributes(&pMap);
    if (NULL == pMap)
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("Couldn't get the attribute list from the given IXMLDOMNode.");
        return false;
    }

    IXMLDOMNode* pVirtualNode = NULL;
    pMap->getNamedItem(pwszAttributeNameInWChar, &pVirtualNode);
    if (NULL == pVirtualNode)
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("Couldn't find the given attribute name.");
        return false;
    }

    VARIANT var;
    VariantInit(&var);
    pVirtualNode->get_nodeValue(&var);

    nRequiredBytes = WideCharToMultiByte(::GetACP(), 0, V_BSTR(&var), -1, pszResultText, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (nRequiredBytes > nBufferSizeInBytes)
    {
        //      NtlAssertFail("The buffer size is not enough to take the whole attribute value.");
        return false;
    }

    WideCharToMultiByte(GetACP(), 0, V_BSTR(&var), -1, pszResultText, nBufferSizeInBytes, NULL, NULL);
    return true;
}

bool CNtlXMLDoc::GetDataWithXPath(WCHAR* pwszXPath, WCHAR* pwszResultData, int nBufferSizeInWChars)
{
    if (NULL == pwszXPath || NULL == pwszResultData || 0 >= nBufferSizeInWChars)
        return false;

    IXMLDOMNode* pNode = NULL;    
    m_pXMLDocument->selectSingleNode(pwszXPath, &pNode);

    if(!pNode)
        return false;

    BSTR bstr = NULL;
    if (FAILED(pNode->get_text(&bstr)))
    {
        ::SysFreeString(bstr);
        pNode->Release();           
        return false;
    }

    wcscpy_s(pwszResultData, nBufferSizeInWChars, bstr);

    ::SysFreeString(bstr);
    pNode->Release();

    return true;
}

bool CNtlXMLDoc::GetDataWithXPath(char* pszXPath, char* pszResultData, int nBufferSizeInBytes)
{
    if (NULL == pszXPath || NULL == pszResultData || 0 >= nBufferSizeInBytes)
        return false;

    WCHAR wszUnicodeXPath[1024 + 1];

    int iRequiredChars = ::MultiByteToWideChar(GetACP(), 0, pszXPath, -1, NULL, 0);
    if (_countof(wszUnicodeXPath) < iRequiredChars)
        return false;

    int iWrittenChars = ::MultiByteToWideChar(GetACP(), 0, pszXPath, -1, wszUnicodeXPath, _countof(wszUnicodeXPath));
    if (0 == iWrittenChars)
        return false;
    wszUnicodeXPath[_countof(wszUnicodeXPath) - 1] = L'\0';

    WCHAR wszUnicodeResultData[1024 + 1];
    if (false == GetDataWithXPath(wszUnicodeXPath, wszUnicodeResultData, _countof(wszUnicodeResultData)))
        return false;

    iRequiredChars = ::WideCharToMultiByte(GetACP(), 0, wszUnicodeResultData, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (nBufferSizeInBytes < iRequiredChars)
        return false;

    iWrittenChars = ::WideCharToMultiByte(GetACP(), 0, wszUnicodeResultData, -1, pszResultData, nBufferSizeInBytes, NULL, NULL);
    if (0 == iWrittenChars)
        return false;
    pszResultData[nBufferSizeInBytes - 1] = '\0';

    return true;
}

/**
* XML ÆÄÀÏÀÇ ÇüÅÂ¸¦ TabÀ» ÀÌ¿ëÇØ¼­ º¸±â ÁÁ°Ô Á¤·ÄÇÑ´Ù.
* \param szIndentFileName Á¤·Ä¿¡ »ç¿ëÇÒ ½ºÅ¸ÀÏ ½ÃÆ® ÆÄÀÏ¸í
* return ¼º°ø À¯¹«
*/
bool CNtlXMLDoc::SetIndent(WCHAR* szIndentFileName)
{
    IXMLDOMDocument* pXSL = NULL;
    CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DOMDocument30), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IXMLDOMDocument), (void**)&pXSL);
    if(!pXSL)
        return false;

    VARIANT_BOOL vBool;
    pXSL->put_async(VARIANT_FALSE);
    pXSL->load((_variant_t)szIndentFileName, &vBool);

    VARIANT vObject;
    VariantInit(&vObject);
    vObject.vt = VT_DISPATCH;
    vObject.pdispVal = m_pXMLDocument;

    m_pXMLDocument->transformNodeToObject(pXSL, vObject);

    if(pXSL)
    {
        pXSL->Release();
        pXSL = NULL;
    }

    return true;
}

IXMLDOMDocument* CNtlXMLDoc::GetDocument(void)
{
    return m_pXMLDocument;
}
```

NtlXmlDoc.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <oleauto.h>
#include "msxml2.h"

// WARNING :
// Only 1 CNtlXMLDoc object is allowed to be created in 1 thread.
// This library is not responsible for any problem which occurs when you create 2 or more CNtlXMLDoc objects in the same thread.
// - YOSHIKI
class CNtlXMLDoc
{
public:
    enum EMaxConstants
    {
        MAX_UNICODE_FILE_NAME_LENGTH = 128,
        MAX_UNICODE_XPATH_LENGTH = 128,
        MAX_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IN_WCHAR = 1024
    };

public:
    CNtlXMLDoc(void);
    virtual ~CNtlXMLDoc(void);

    bool Create();
    bool Destroy();

protected:
    void Init();    

public:
    bool Load(WCHAR* pwszFileName, LONG* lLineNumber, BSTR* bstrErrorReasonString);
    bool Load(WCHAR* pwszFileName);
    bool Load(char* pszFileName);

    bool LoadXML(char* szXMLBuffer);                    ///< ¹öÆÛ·ÎºÎÅÍ XML ³»¿ëÀ» ÀÐ¾îµéÀÎ´Ù. (by agebreak)
    bool LoadXML(WCHAR* wszXMLBuffer);

    IXMLDOMNode* SelectSingleNode(WCHAR* pwszXPath);
    IXMLDOMNode* SelectSingleNode(char* pszXPath);

    IXMLDOMNodeList* SelectNodeList(WCHAR* pwszXPath);
    IXMLDOMNodeList* SelectNodeList(char* pszXPath);

    bool GetTextWithAttributeName(IXMLDOMNode* pNode, WCHAR* pwszAttributeName, WCHAR* pwszResultText, int nBufferSizeInWChars);
    bool GetTextWithAttributeName(IXMLDOMNode* pNode, char* pszAttributeName, char* pszResultText, int nBufferSizeInBytes);

    bool GetDataWithXPath(WCHAR* pwszXPath, WCHAR* pwszResultData, int nBufferSizeInWChars);
    bool GetDataWithXPath(char* pszXPath, char* pszResultData, int nBufferSizeInBytes);

    IXMLDOMDocument* GetDocument(void);
    bool SetIndent(WCHAR* szIndentFileName);           ///< XMLÆÄÀÏÀ» ÀúÀåÇÒ¶§ ¿­À» ¸ÂÃá´Ù.
    
protected:
    static DWORD m_dwNumberOfCreatedInstances;

    IXMLDOMDocument* m_pXMLDocument;

    bool m_bIsFileLoaded;
};
```

Algunos errores que me muestra la consola:

```
 LNK2019    símbolo externo "public: bool __thiscall CNtlXMLDoc::GetTextWithAttributeName(struct IXMLDOMNode *,char *,char *,int)" (?GetTextWithAttributeName@CNtlXMLDoc@@QAE_NPAUIXMLDOMNode@@PAD1H@Z) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "protected: static int __cdecl CNtlScriptEncrypter::LoadConfigOptionXML(struct _SConfigData *,char *)" (?LoadConfigOptionXML@CNtlScriptEncrypter@@KAHPAU_SConfigData@@PAD@Z)
```

Lo estoy compilando en VS 2019 con MFC y VC Compiler 2010. Creo que vinculé todas las librerias y encabezados en las propiedades del proyecto.

Tengo unos 23 errores casi identicos al de arriba, todos en el mismo archivo obj y que hacen referencia a funciones de NtlXMLDoc.

Si pueden tirarme algún consejo sería genial. Gracias!

*El proyecto no está creado por mí, fue un código liberado hace un tiempo y lo estoy intentando arreglar*

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor poner el NtlXMLDoc.h? Gracias

Comment: Por supuesto! Lo acabo de agregar, gracias por tu comentario!

Comment: ¿Todo forma parte del mismo proyecto?, es decir el archivo  NtlXmlDoc.h y NtlXmlDoc.cpp están junto al NtlScriptEncrypter.cpp en el mismo proyecto.

Comment: Pertenecen a la misma solución, pero son distintos proyectos, algo así
https://pasteboard.co/K5g1WSF.png

Comment: Ah, entonces tú problema está en que no estás incluyendo la librería del Doc al proyecto quee te da error. Cuando gweberas  la librería se genera un archivos  .Lib en el directorio debug o reléase del proyecto . Haz referencia a ese archivo Lib en las opciones de vinculación del otro proyecto. Librerías adicionales. Lo pones con la ruta completa y nombre completos.

Comment: O agrégale  la referencia a ese proyecto y no  haces nada del comentario anterior.

Comment: Si, incluí en las propiedades del proyecto el .lib generado, pero aún así no funciona correctamente, por eso me parece extraño

Comment: Agrega al proyecto una referencia hacia el proyecto del XML Doc. Click derecho Agregar Referencias y en la Sección proyecto escoje el proyecto de  la librería. Quizá el lib generado no lo estás poniendo correctamente o tu proyecto está con un enlace dinámico o algo por el estilo. Pero de qué no encuentra la lib no la encuentra. Agregando la referencia debe encontrarla.

Comment: Vale, lo intentaré, muchas gracias por tu comentario. Te confirmo si funcionó apenas lo intente, gracias

Comment: Y si eso no funciona tú problema entonces está en la convención de llamada cdecl/ stdcall

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Sí, funcionó incluir el proyecto desde la referencia! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, no sé como no me di cuenta de ello antes xD. Gracias devuelta, eres un crack!

Comment: Voy a poner el comentario como respuesta

Comment: Dale! Muchas gracias devuelta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega al proyecto una referencia hacia el proyecto del XML Doc:

- En el nombre del proyecto que utiliza la librería das cick derechi
- Seleccionas Agregar Referencias
- Vas  a la Sección proyecto
- Selecciona el proyecto de la librería.